# how to implement efficient add in C++ templated list class

Tags: c++, templates, placement-new

Suppose we have a templated c++ list class. Yes, vector exists, but the point is to know how to handle this problem.

The Constructor allocates a block of n objects of type T but does not initialize because they are not used yet.

In the add method, we wish to copy in a new object, but using operator = is not possible because operator = would first destroy the existing object, which was never initialized.  How does one copy in an object into data[used] ?

```
#include <string>
template<typename T>
class DynArray {
private:
  int capacity;
  int used;
  T* data;
public:
  DynArray(int initialCap) : capacity(initialCap), used(0), data((T*)new char[sizeof(T)*capacity]) {}
  void add(const T& e) {
    //TODO: if the dynarray is full, grow
    data[used++] = e; //ERROR! Should use copy constructor!!!
  }
};

int main() {
  DynArray<std::string> a(5);
  a.add(std::string("abc"));
}
```

Comment: Look for articles explaining "placement new".

Comment: Do note that `new char[sizeof(T)*capacity]` may not give you a buffer with correct alignment for `T`.  This can be an issue.  Ideally you should allocate a buffer aligned to `T`.  You can do that by using `std::allocator` if that is allowed.

Comment: Are you trying to create a dynamic Array class or a Linked-List(as List is indicated in the title) class?

Answer (score 2):

You should use placement new:

```
void add(const T& e) {
    //TODO: if the dynarray is full, grow
    new (data + used) T(e);
    used++;
 }
```

Placement new constructs an object in already allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are attempting to do, you need to call `T`'s [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) using [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). And don't forget to implement the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) as well:

```
template<typename T>
class DynArray {
private:
  int capacity;
  int used;
  T* data;

public:
  DynArray(int initialCap = 0) : capacity(0), used(0), data(0) {
    reserve(initialCap);
  }

  DynArray(const DynArray &src) : capacity(0), used(0), data(0) {
    reserve(src.capacity);
    for(int i = 0; i < src.used; ++i) {
      add(src.data[i]);
    }
  }

  // C++11 and higher only...
  DynArray(DynArray &&src) : capacity(src.capacity), used(src.used), data(src.data) {
    src.capacity = src.used = 0;
    src.data = 0;
  }

  ~DynArray() {
    clear();
    delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);
  }

  DynArray& operator=(const DynArray &rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
      DynArray(rhs).swap(*this);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  // C++11 and higher only...
  DynArray& operator=(DynArray &&rhs) {
    DynArray(std::move(rhs)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }

  void swap(DynArray &other) {
    std::swap(data, other.data);
    std::swap(used, other.used);
    std::swap(capacity, other.capacity);
  }

  void clear() {
    resize(0);
  }

  void reserve(int newCap) {
    // TODO: round up newCap to an even block size...
    if (newCap <= capacity) return;
    T *newData = reinterpret_cast<T*>(new char[sizeof(T) * newCap]);
    for(int i = 0; i < used; ++i) {
      new (newData + i) T(data[i]);
    }
    delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);
    data = newData;
    capacity = newCap;
  }

  void resize(int newSize) {
    if (newSize < 0) newSize = 0;
    if (newSize == used) return;
    if (newSize > used) {
      reserve(newSize);
      for(int i = used; i < newSize; ++i) {
        new (data + i) T();
        ++used;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(int i = used-1; i >= newSize; --i) {
        data[i]->~T();
        --used;
      }
    }
  }

  void add(const T& e) {
    if (used == capacity) {
        reserve(capacity * 1.5);
    }
    new (data + used) T(e);
    ++used;
  }
};
```

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  DynArray<std::string> a(5);
  a.add("abc");
}
```

Comment: In the end, If I write placement new I still would have to just copy. Placement new would seem to buy nothing over memcpy(data+used, &e, sizeof(e));

Comment: @Dov `placement-new` calls constructors, `memcpy()` does not. You can't use `memcpy()` unless `T` is a [trivially-copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) type.

Answer (score 0):

The `DynArray` class has a type of `T`, so you should simply allocate an array of type T  with size of `initialCap`, which is simply

```
new T[initialCap];
```

For built-in types, e.g. int, the elements are left uninitialized.

For others, like string, the default constructor of T is called to initialize the elements.

> In the add method, we wish to copy in a new object, but using operator = is not possible because operator = would first destroy the existing object

`data[used++] = e;` This is perfectly fine. It assigns `e` to `data[used]` - calls the assignment operator of the string, and it won't cause any troubles. However, when your array grows, you would need to allocate new arrays with double capacity, copy over the elements, and destroy the old data.

Comment: Agreed, but I suspect the asker is going through the extra pain to avoid the costs of default construction of unused array elements.

Comment: Calling the constructor n times for an empty list is a nonstarter.